# JQuery - Group Checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following code which expands and collapses a subcategory when the arrow image is clicked.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
 function toggleTableRows()
 {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.parent')
           .css("cursor","pointer")
           .toggle(
              function() {
                 $(this).attr("title","Click to Collapse")
                 $(this).attr("src","arrow_expanded.gif");
                 $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
              },
              function() {
                 $(this).attr("title","Click to Expand");
                 $(this).attr("src","arrow_collapsed.gif");
                 $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
              }
          );

          initCheckBoxes();
  });
}

function toggleCheckboxes(current, form, field) {
        $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ field +"[]']").attr("checked", current.checked);
}

function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {
        var checked = ($("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']").length == $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']:checked").length);
        $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name.replace("[]", "") +"']").attr("checked", checked);
}

function initCheckBoxes() {
    $("#frmDinnerMenu :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        if (this.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, "") == "chk[]") {
                toggleParentCheckboxes(this, "frmDinnerMenu");
        }
    });
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">toggleTableRows();</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="frmDinnerMenu" id="frmDinnerMenu" method="POST" action="">
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><img class="parent" id="0" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Fruits</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk0" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk0');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apple</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Banana</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="false" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Orange</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="true" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><img class="parent" id="1" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Vegetables</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk1');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabbage</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tomatoes</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Green Peppers</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><img class="parent" id="2" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Dessert</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chk2" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk2');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-2><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ice Cream</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk2[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-2><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Custard</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk2[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-2><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chocolate Cake</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk2[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that when the form is posted, I get the following output

```
[chk0] => Array ( 
                  [0] => true 
                  [1] => true 
                ) 
.....
.......
```

How can I make sure I get the posted values like this:

```
[chk0] => Array ( 
                  [0] => true 
                  [2] => true 
                )
```

The idea is to modify the JavaScript functions and HTML code so the checkbox toggling works and also the POSTED values contain the keys of the checked checkboxes instead of sequential values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing the names of your inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk0[apple]" value="true" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk0[orange]" value="true" />
```

This should result with an array in php keyed by "apple" and "orange"

Of course, if you change the checkbox names, the javascript that looks for the `chk0[]` as the name will need to change slightly:

```
function toggleCheckboxes(current, form, field) {
        // search for name begining with 'field[' to find children checkboxes
        $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name^='"+ field +"[']").attr("checked", current.checked);
}

function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {
        var $form = $("#"+form);
        var category = current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "");

        // figure out if there are any unchecked checkboxes in the current category:
        if ($form.find(":checkbox[name^='"+category+"[']:not(:checked)").length)
        {
           $form.find(":checkbox[name="+category+"]").removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
           $form.find(":checkbox[name="+category+"]").attr('checked', checked);
        }
}

function initCheckBoxes() {
    $("#frmDinnerMenu :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        // matches chk0[whatever]
        if (this.name.match(/chk[0-9]\[.*\]/)) {
                toggleParentCheckboxes(this, "frmDinnerMenu");
        }
    });
}
```

You coud also change the "value" of the checked element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk0[]" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk0[]" value="orange" />
```

This will result in the same array you are getting but with more useful values for the checked elements.

Comment: I tried changing the checbox name to use an index like chk0[0], chk0[1], chk0[2],. Probably this is what I want, but the toggling of checkboxes fails. Try out the above code and check what I mean.. Thanks – Vincent

Comment: @Vincent - Your javascript was specifically looking for chk0[] as a name, you can change that to look for names starting with 'chk0[' - plus there were a few other points to change there... look at my comments in the javascript section

Comment: This seems to work right, except that, the parent checkbox should be checked only if all the subcategories are checked.

Comment: @Vincent - rewrote `toggleParentCheckboxes` for that logic - sorry

Comment: @gnarf -> Thanks for looking into it, but it's still not working. Can you please check the toggleParentCheckboxes logic again?

Answer (score 2):

Change the names to use a index, chk0[0], chk0[1], chk0[2], ...

Ex:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk0[0]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk0[1]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/>
...
```

Comment: I tried changing the checbox name to use an index. Probably this is what I want, but the toggling of checkboxes fails. Try out the above code and check what I mean..

Thanks